# two concurrent connections/requests locks

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I have a single page website in javascript.

To simplify everything three types of http requests are sent to the server

```
/action/status/
/action/csv_process/
/action/status_pid/
```

Every 30 second the `/action/status/` request is sent to the server. There is not much happening in the request. You can see below all write mysql queries executed in the request

```
2017-01-12 18:37:03 2 --- REQUEST START: action status
2017-01-12 18:37:03 2 UPDATE `log_login` SET time_active=1387 WHERE id=78360
2017-01-12 18:37:03 2 BEGIN
2017-01-12 18:37:03 2 COMMIT
2017-01-12 18:37:03 2 --- REQUEST END 0.076473951339722
```

Then the user can upload CSV files. When the files are uploaded the user can select how the file has to be processed. The following `/action/csv_process/` request often takes some time to complete so a `/action/status_pid/` request is sent to the server every 3 second to get a progress in percent (0-100)

Everything works fine. The `/action/status_pid/` requests run with the 3 second intervals and return a response while `/action/csv_process/` is processing, but as soon as the `/action/status/` is sent to the server everything locks until `/action/csv_process/` is completed

Why is `/action/status/` locking everything?

Every request runs with mysql transactions and all tables are `InnoDB`

Even though if I didn't use `session_write_close()` at all the concurrency requests should just wait until the current request is done.. But `/action/status/` is pending until the data process request is done and locks all other requests with pending

Comment: Is your table engine MyISAM or InnoDB? And I didn't understand the `UPDATE` followed by `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` .. Shouldn't be between begin and commit?

Comment: All tables are InnoDB. Yes, you are right about the begin/commit queries..

Answer (score 1):

If you use session it could be locking one request until you release session. After session is no longer needed try to call 
[session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Comment: I do not use `session_write_close` in the `/action/status/`.. But it should not lock everything completely.. Even the request `/action/status/` is pending until the data process request is done..

Comment: After `/action/status/` is sent everything stops until the data process is completed

Comment: @clarkk but when you use session in all these end points until response is sent only one action per time will be executed. Rest will wait for session storage lock release

Comment: I know.. But all requests stops (pending).. `/action/status/` is pending until the data process is completed

Comment: Are there any shared resources between this requests? Db or files? In db transaction check isolation level which you use

Comment: no.. you can see which write quieries are done in the status request

Comment: Maybe problem isn't in server side but in client? Try do those request from postman or other rest client